Extract all files of a file type from zip files that begin with a particular string
I get some files sent to me on a weekly basis which begin with the same characters and date, and anything after that can differ from week to week.
I have some basic code that extracts the PDF files when given the exact zip file name, but I'm hoping to move away from that by having a procedure which uses wildcards. So anything that is a zip file that begins with that string - extract the PDFs and put them all in a folder named as today's date.
Ex: Geography_20240807_010028.zip, Geography_20240807_010028_3.zip, Geography_20240807_010029.zip
Is there a way to loop through and extract the PDFs from all zip files starting with Geography_(todaysdate) rather than running each one at a time?
**editing to add that I figured out how to unzip all files from folders that begin with a particular string - but I am not sure how to combine the two so I only pull in the PDFs from the zip
'First script that gets PDFs

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set app = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Sub ExtractByExtension(fldr, ext, dst)
  For Each f In fldr.Items
    If f.Type = "File folder" Then
      ExtractByExtension f.GetFolder, ext, dst
    ElseIf LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(f.Name)) = LCase(ext) Then
      app.NameSpace(dst).CopyHere f.Path
    End If
  Next
End Sub

ExtractByExtension app.NameSpace("C:\Work\Geography_20240807_010028.zip"), "pdf", "C:\Work\20240807"

'Second script that extracts all files

    Set re = New RegExp
    re.Pattern = "^Geography.*\.Zip$"
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set app = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    
    ExtractTo = "C:\Work\20240807"
    
    For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\Work\").Files
      If re.Test(f.Name) Then
        Set FilesInZip = app.NameSpace(f.Path).Items
        app.NameSpace(ExtractTo).CopyHere(FilesInZip)
      End If
    Next

